# Why cloudera imports are present in sqoop autogen file

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera, sqoop

I'm not using any hadoop distributions like `Cloudera` or `Hortonworks`. I've got 3 machines with `hadoop` installed and configured as master, slave1 and slave2 respectively. I've got mysql on `master` with a database `userdb` and table `emp`. Then I've got `sqoop` installed and configured on slave1 and I ran the `sqoop codegen` command as follows:

```
sqoop codegen --connect jdbc:mysql://master/userdb --username root --P --table emp
```

It generated `emp.java`, `emp.class` and `emp.jar` files in `tmp/sqoop-hadoop/compile/xxxx`. When I viewed `emp.java` it had the following imports along with a dozen more:

```
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.JdbcWritableBridge;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.DelimiterSet;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.FieldFormatter;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.RecordParser;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.BooleanParser;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.BlobRef;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.ClobRef;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.LargeObjectLoader;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.lib.SqoopRecord;
```

I'm just wondering how cloudera packages are present in a sqoop `autogen` file. Can somebody please explain me.